# PL SQL find duplicate in collection

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have collection like below.

```
ID       NAME
-----     -------
1          A
2          A
3          B
4          C
```

I want to check whether any duplicate values there in the collection. is it possible in pl/sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use plsql's built in set operator "set" to create a set with unique values and compare it with original collection. Then you can use another set operator "except" to get them:

```
DECLARE
  type tt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
  orig tt;
  tmp  tt;
BEGIN
  orig := tt('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a');
  tmp  := SET(orig);
  IF (tmp.count = orig.count) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('no duplicates');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('there are duplicates:');
    tmp := SET(orig MULTISET except tmp);
    FOR i IN 1 .. tmp.count
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(tmp(i));
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: When I am trying to pass values as input parameter .. I am getting below error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DIST_CALC_ID_ARRAY'.. please note, I have input parameter as array of integers..